# Where can I find the descriptin of LibreOffice API for BASIC

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I wanted to create a few macros for LibreOffice using BASIC. However I cannot find the API description. It is absent in help as well as in interet. When I try to google it I get masses of examples in C++, Java, Python, but not a single www with BASIC.

For example where from can I get the hierarchy of objects and their methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LibreOffice Basic uses essentially the same API as PyUNO and Java.  That is, they all use the UNO API.  To get started, the [OpenOffice development guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Basic/Accessing_the_UNO_API) helpfully describes the two main ways to step into the object hierarchy, the `Global` variables `ThisComponent` and, less commonly, `StarDesktop`.  There also is a specialty variant in LO Base, `ThisDatabaseDocument`.  To get the properties and methods of these objects, execute `MsgBox oObject.DBG_properties` or `.DBG_methods`.  It often is easier to copy the longer lists that are returned by this method into a text editor for searching.  You will find that all, or nearly all, of the methods and properties you reveal will be described in the [LibreOffice UNO IDL API](http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/index.html).  The documentation for the API is not that descriptive, but you will be able to fill in some essential details using that resource  Every `Object` has properties that can be reviewed by `.DBG_properties`.

The key properties for navigating the object hierarchy are `.Parent`, `.Model`, `.CurrentController` and occasionally `.Source`.  The key methods are `getByName()` and `getByIndex()`.  It also is helpful that events which trigger macros typically return an event object whose source or parent is the object that initiated the macro, for example, a command button.  This object can be accessed by referring to it along with the `Sub`, i.e., `Sub SubName (oEventObject As Variant)`....